# I received this code error each time I tried to start my bot up 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: discord.js

I have tried everything and cannot figure it out.

```
Error: The module '/home/container/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 115. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

tried using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`, Re-installing it.